# How to fill DTO object Spatie in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I use DTO from Spatie in Laravel.

The DTO model looks like:

```
<?php

namespace Domain\Subscriber\DataTransferObjects;

use Spatie\LaravelData\Data;


class Rating {
    public int $rateid;
    public int $rate;

}

class RateData extends Data
{

    public Rating $rating = array();

    public function __construct() {

    }
}
```

I fetch the request inside controller:

```
{"rating": [{"rateid": 1, "rate": 4}]}
```

How to fill the DTO by this request?

Controller is:

```
class RateController extends Controller
{


    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $RateData = new RateData()
        $service->setRate();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see no point in wrapping Rating in RateData, as it is just simple data.

```
class Rating extends Data
{
    public int $rateid;
    public int $rate;
}
```

In your controller.

```
foreach ($request->get('rating') as $ratingData) {
    $rating = Rating::from(
        [
            'rateid' => $ratingData['rateid'],
            'rate' => $ratingData['rate'],
        ]
    );
}
```

Just a general tip, keep consistent with naming, that is gonna help you in the long run.

Pascal case is used for `$RateData` and the `DTO`, uses all lowercase on `$rateid;`. `PHP` property for an example should be camel cased. `$rateId` or `$rateData`.

Comment: Could you check my new question, please

Comment: Cannot assign null to property App\\Data\\RateData::$rateid of type int

Comment: Your data is in array so you have to iterate over it, updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

Not directly related to OP question but just to complete @mrhn answer.

When working with an array of data you want to all convert to DTO, you can use `::collect()` like so;

```php
$ratings = Rating::collect($request->input("rating"));
```

It then gives you access to all [Laravel `Collection` methods](https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/collections#available-methods).

see [Spatie docs](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-data/v4/as-a-resource/from-data-to-array#content-using-collections)